# Identifying streets of same name where split by osm

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, splitting

I have a large map of every street in the country.
This is a vector layer in QGIS
many streets are split by OSM , IE have a different OSM ID yet the street has the same name.
Often these streets are split at intersecting points.
Ideally I'd like to join them using Qgis and then export my shapefile
My software previously looked at points in a route and determined if the street the user was on, or turning onto, continued or ended at the intersection: hence allowing me to determine road rules for the intersection.
For example our main street is one road, but is split into about 10 sections.
Is there an "easy" way to join streets or determine if the street is the entire street or just a section of the street ?

Comment: @ChrisW, looks like that duplicate's answers only give PostGIS solutions!

Comment: @Simbamangu You're absolutely right - apparently I just completely misread it last night, as I thought I saw in there someone had eventually posted a way to *do* it in QGIS but they were actually talking about *checking* it.

Comment: Found the other one: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/67057/merge-lines-with-the-same-name-attribute-on-qgis

Answer (score 1):

ArcGIS has a tool called Dissolve that can do this, though from what I read the QGIS equivalent only does polygons. [That article](http://www.jordanteichmann.ca/posts/dissolving-lines-in-quantum-gis) mentioned you can still do it with "Vector > Geometry Tools > Singleparts to Multiparts" The (much) slower alternative would be an attribute selection for each name and then merging the geometry of those records.

Comment: Hmmm, the problem is that using disolve or Singleparts to multiparts is there are many streets ( in the same country) with the same name, I need to merge streets with the same name if the location is ( roughly) the same

Comment: Arc's tool has an option to allow multipart features or not - I don't know if the qgis tool does, but if it doesn't you could always run an explode (or the reverse 'multipart to single part') tool. That should break the lines up so that only connected segments share a record.