# Why osmId is not the same across the same road?

Tags: openstreetmap, road

I download .shp and .dbf files for roads, extract it and save to database. I display points with the same name of street on my own Google Map. This is how it looks like:
[image]

I was interested in how osmID works, so on each marker I marked the osmID along with its coordinates. And I found out that there are several different osmIDs along the same street with the same name. Here you can see it (the first line is osmID):
[image]

But I would like to get all points across the same road, not partial content. Is there any way to get all points across the same road ? There are several roads with the same name across my country. How osmID really works? Distance between this two points show on a screen is 180 meters, in my project it is too great a distance to be able to implement the idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OpenStreetMap IDs are given for each segment of a OSM way (in this case the road). In OpenStreetMap roads need to be split in segments when attributes change, for example the maximum speed or the surface conditions. Also, they need to be split to accomodate different bus routes etc.

Please note that OpenStreetMap IDs are also not guaranteed to be stable, that is it is perfectly possible, though not wanted, that someone deletes a segment of the road and uploads it again under a different ID.

Comment: So, is it possible to get whole road, because by name it's impossible - as i sad there are roads with the same name. In data i extract from .shp and .dbf there are no fields that could gives me this kind of information.

Comment: Yes it is with GIS software, e.g. QGIS, see this gis.SE question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/67057/merge-lines-with-the-same-name-attribute-on-qgis